# How to download maven dependency as a jar file?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I want to download `org.ops4j.base.io` dependency as a JAR file in a testing folder. I tried this command:

```sh
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get -Dartifact=org.ops4j.base:ops4j-base-io:1.5.0:jar:sources -Dmaven.repo.local=/path/to/folder
```

This didn't downloaded the dependency as a JAR file, instead it downloaded as folders. How can I resolve this issue?

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ops4j/base/ops4j-base-io/1.5.0/
How can I download the jar file from the command line?

Comment: What do you mean by "as folders"? Is the jar not inside one of the folders?

Comment: @f1sh i meant it created all the artifacts like org, ops4j and so on.like all the folders in m2 repo.yes the jar is inside the relevant artifact but i want to `download only the jar`. how can i do it?

Comment: Define the dependency in scope test ... and you have it available on test classpath for testing purpose...no need to manually download artifacts via dependency plugin etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise you meant downloading it from pom file?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), because I can't readily think of a reason you'd want to do this.

Comment: Just add a dependency in your pom file and the download will be done automatically by Maven...